# Dermatitis exfoliate the most possible etiology

Tags: face, elderly-seniors-aged-old, outer-external-ear

This geriatric patient has reccurent erythroderma and he is also on tuberculosis treatment.

And this is how he looks
[image: abdoment]

[image: face and ear]

So, what might be the possible cause?